# Failed to launch home screen widget in iOS 14 Simulator

Tags: widget, ios14

Error Details:

> SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error
> Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code=8 "Failed to show
> Widget 'com.anupam.iOS14Feature.widgetExtension' error: Error
> Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=2 "Please specify
> the widget kind in the scheme's Environment Variables using the key
> '_XCWidgetKind' to be one of: 'BillPayCheckerWidget',
> 'CommitCheckerWidget'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Please specify
> the widget kind in the scheme's Environment Variables using the key
> '_XCWidgetKind' to be one of: 'BillPayCheckerWidget',
> 'CommitCheckerWidget'}." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to
> show Widget 'com.anupam.iOS14Feature.widgetExtension' error: Error
> Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=2 "Please specify
> the widget kind in the scheme's Environment Variables using the key
> '_XCWidgetKind' to be one of: 'BillPayCheckerWidget',
> 'CommitCheckerWidget'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Please specify
> the widget kind in the scheme's Environment Variables using the key
> '_XCWidgetKind' to be one of: 'BillPayCheckerWidget',
> 'CommitCheckerWidget'}., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc70d618350 {Error
> Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=2 "Please specify
> the widget kind in the scheme's Environment Variables using the key
> '_XCWidgetKind' to be one of: 'BillPayCheckerWidget',
> 'CommitCheckerWidget'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Please specify
> the widget kind in the scheme's Environment Variables using the key
> '_XCWidgetKind' to be one of: 'BillPayCheckerWidget',
> 'CommitCheckerWidget'}}} Domain: DTXMessage Code: 1
> --
>
> System Information
>
> macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G73) Xcode 12.0 (17200.1)

Answer (score 6):

likely because you changed the kind string inside of your :widget struct. Go to edit your scheme, and in arguments, change the name of _XCWidgetKind to one of your new kind names. Literally just loaded this fix into my simulator as i typed this lol.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I have two widgets.  Each one runs fine independently, but when I add them to a WidgetBundle and set the @main wrapper to the bundle and remove it from each of the Widgets I get the same error.  There are no entries for the _XCWidgetKind value when I run each widget independently. 
Any ideas on what the issue is and how to resolve it?

Comment: @StewartLynch, I get the same problem too. this article solved the problem.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657599

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple widgets, in my case I have two widget.

1. Static Configuration widget
2. Intent Configuration widget

And, when you run your widget extension target, you need to specify which widget you want to run.

Product -> Scheme -> Edit scheme

1. Enable `_XCWidgetKind` and provide the wiget struct name [in my case "Selectable_OTP_Extn"]
2. Enable `XCWidgetDefaultView` & `_XCWidgetFamily`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried other answers but for multiple Widgets (i.e. `WidgetBundle`) only this answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64000716/2095408 (comment other Widgets and leave just 1 Widget uncommented).

Comment: _XCWidgetKind was enabled or disabled (I mean the checkbox on the left)?

Comment: Enabled I think...

Answer (score 0):

If you have many different widgets in your app, you need to tell Xcode which one you are going to debug, you can't debug all of them at the same time, that's what _XCWidgetKind is for, so add the Class name of your widget works.