# iOS14 Intents on small widget only

Tags: xcode, widget, ios14, widgetkit

I have a widget with Intents configured for my iOS 14 app.  For the small widget, the intent is necessary because I can only fit half of the information that I could display so I give the user what half to display through the intent selection.  For the medium sized widget it is not necessary because I can fit all information side by side in an HStack.
Is there a way to enable the intent for only certain families of widgets?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible, I have to create two widgets, one static and one with intents and then place them in a Widget Bundle.
This "Should" work fine, but I am getting another error that is the same as [Failed to launch home screen widget in iOS 14 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451273/failed-to-launch-home-screen-widget-in-ios-14-simulator) but the answer does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this in your widget body

```
 .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium])
```