# Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID

Tags: swift, xcode, widget

I just added the widget to my project, but I get this error and the app does not build successfully.
I just added the widget to a blank project and now I get this error.
Anyone else in the same situation?

Xcode 14.2

```
Details

SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code=8 "Failed to show Widget 'com.ur73nx.CDWidget.test.test-widget' error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000038fc9c0 {Error Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (com.ur73nx.CDWidget.test.test-widget)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (com.ur73nx.CDWidget.test.test-widget)}}, FBSOpenApplicationRequestID=0xa62a, NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed.}." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to show Widget 'com.ur73nx.CDWidget.test.test-widget' error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000038fc9c0 {Error Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (com.ur73nx.CDWidget.test.test-widget)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (com.ur73nx.CDWidget.test.test-widget)}}, FBSOpenApplicationRequestID=0xa62a, NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed.}., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000038fc990 {Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000038fc9c0 {Error Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (com.ur73nx.CDWidget.test.test-widget)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (com.ur73nx.CDWidget.test.test-widget)}}, FBSOpenApplicationRequestID=0xa62a, NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed.}}}
Domain: DTXMessage
Code: 1
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-12-20 01:56:08 +0000";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.1 (Build 22C65)
Xcode 14.2 (21534) (Build 14C18)
Timestamp: 2022-12-20T10:56:08+09:00
```

I want build successfully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625506/failed-to-get-descriptors-for-extensionbundleid)

Answer (score 0):

when i was face the same problem was the excluded arm64 architecture for any iOS simulator on the widget target build settings (Added because of my M1 development device).

When removing this excluded architecture, the widget is running without any problem.

Comment: I don't excluded  the arm64 architecture on the widget target build settings.So,I can't fix it by this way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).